# Adding a form action to a config page

Tags: php, forms, silverstripe

I've been trying to make an extension to add some function to the CMS. As it's a setting for the CMS I've added it to the settings tab. While I can take values and save them I needed an action on the page to synchronise a system and I can't get my action to be called, here is my code.

```
private static $db = array(
    'Path' => 'Varchar(50)',
);

private static $allowed_actions = array (
    'update',
);

public function updateCMSFields(FieldList $fields)
{
    $fields->addFieldsToTab('Root.Importer', array(
        ImporterPathField::create('Path', 'Path')->setDescription('Path to area'),
        FormAction::create('update', 'Synchronise')
    ));
}

public function update() {
    SS_Log::add_writer(new SS_LogEmailWriter('test@example.com'), SS_Log::ERR);

}
```

It doesn't get called. If I need to add the function to the left nav rather than part of the settings I'm ok with that too but I also tried that with even less success. Is it possible to get the action called on button press?

Answer (score 3):

You need to place the `$allowed_actions` and the `update` method in an extension for `CMSSettingsController`. Also you should probably put the `FormAction` into the CMSActions list.

Here's how I would do this:

**SiteConfigExtension.php**

```
class SiteConfigExtension extends DataExtension
{
    private static $db = array(
        'Path' => 'Varchar(50)',
    );

    public function updateCMSFields(FieldList $fields)
    {
        $fields->addFieldsToTab('Root.Importer', array(
            ImporterPathField::create('Path', 'Path')->setDescription('Path to area')
        ));
    }

    public function updateCMSActions(FieldList $actions)
    {
        $actions->push(
            FormAction::create('update', 'Synchronise')
        );
    }
}
```

**CMSSettingsControllerExtension.php**

```
class CMSSettingsControllerExtension extends DataExtension
{
    private static $allowed_actions = array (
        'update',
    );

    public function update() {
        SS_Log::add_writer(new SS_LogEmailWriter('test@example.com'), SS_Log::ERR);
    }
}
```